# Javascript: refresh IFrame browser specific

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, browser

i need a solution for refreshing an iframe which works for different browsers.

can you confirm, that the code i found on the internet is correct or give me the correct javascript?

IE 7
  `window.document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.location.reload(true);`

IE 8
  `window.document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.location.reload(true);`

IE 9
  `window.document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.location.reload(true);`

Firefox 12-17 
  `window.document.getElementById('iframeId').src = window.document.getElementById('iframeId').src;`

Chrome < 19
  `document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.location.reload();`

Chrome now 
???

Safari and Opera would be nice, but the above are important. the iframe may be in a different domain.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi does this work for IE versions ?? I try to use as mentioned in here but could not reload the iFrame.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome version 23.0.1271.97 i just tried using

`document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.location.reload()`

and it works. 
You could try:

`document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.location.href = document.getElementById('iframeId').contentWindow.location.href`

Answer (score 0):

```
**Try This**
location.reload();
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to problem, it is highly recommended that you provide additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question. Code only answers typically become useless in the long-run because future viewers experiencing similar problems cannot understand the reasoning behind the solution.